# DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library (Running cx_Oracle in anaconda python)

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to an oracle database in a jupyter notebook environment using the `cx_Oracle` library. I've set the settings and configurations then tried to start the connection with `cx_Oracle.connect` but am getting this error:

```
DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library
```

I've found solutions on how to fix this for python (installing instancclient for Oracle and placing dll files in the python directory, but how would I fix this issue for anaconda python to run the connection in a jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 2):

You may also change to [python-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/), which Oracle client is not required.

```
python -m pip install oracledb
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is having a hard time finding Oracle instant client libraries on my Mac M1. Like bkyee mentioned, oracledb is a good work around since by default is doesn't need the oracle instant client.  Here are the steps I use:

```
python -m pip install oracledb --upgrade
```

then change as needed for your setup

```
import pandas as pd
import oracledb

username = 'username'
password = 'password'
host = 'host.name.org'
port = 1521
service = 'SVC'

conn = oracledb.connect(user=username, password=password, host=host, port=port, service_name=service)

df = pd.read_sql_query("select table_name from all_tables", conn)
```

This [site](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html) is helpful if you want some variations for oracledb connect.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to install an Oracle client library for it to work. Your issue is just how to get cx_oracle in your conda env to be able to locate the drivers on your computer.

Putting the dll in the python directory will work, but it's a sloppy fix - the [official installation instructions](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-windows) say:

> Add Oracle 21, 19, 18, 12 or 11.2 client libraries to your operating system library search path such as PATH on Windows or LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Linux. On macOS use init_oracle_client() in your application to pass the Oracle Client directory name, see Using cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client() to set the Oracle Client directory. This is also usable on Windows.

So once you have an Oracle Client installed, the easiest option is to [use cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#usinginitoracleclient)():

```
import cx_Oracle
import sys
import os

cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"C:\oracle\instantclient_19_9")

...the rest of your code...
```

Or you can add that directory to your PATH.

The installation instructions go into a lot more detail.